# Создание админки

Tags: webbrowser, java-ee, java, сервер

Всем привет. )  Извините за мой русский. :(

Подскажите, каким макаром можно создать веб-админку для доступа к базе (добавдения инфы, удаления и т.п. + скачаивание файлов с сервера в разные каталоги на файловой системе клиента - это важно!) через веб, если знаю только java на уровне книги для чайников.

Подскажите, куда копать, чтобы при этом было актуально по технологиям или реально по времени (15 дней - буду негром, который кушает гранит по утрам). "Может аплет!? Ибо это джава на сокетах". Ибо я не знаю, куда смотреть. :(

Answer (score 1):

При текущем уровне, боюсь, за 15 дней вы только разберетесь в технологиях, полистав их showcase-ы.

Возможно, стоит посмотреть на фреймворки, ориентированные на быструю web-разработку: [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) или [Grails](https://grails.org/).

Там вам будет и натягивание объектов на таблицы из коробки, и генерация шаблонов контроллеров и страниц просто из командной строки. В общем все, чтобы быстро, не вникая в детали и особенности, набросать прототип.

Правда, у всего своя цена. Подобные фреймворки привязывают вас к определенной архитектуре, и шаг в сторону от нее становится проблематичным.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь почитать [тут](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud_ru.html?print=yes), например, инструкция, как в NetBeans создать простое приложение для связи с базой данный на основе сущностей.